# Could the Japanese H-IIB carry a payload to the moon?

Tags: jaxa, japan

The Japanese H-IIB seems like an interesting cost effective system.  I see that it can carry a hefty payload into Earth orbit.  Could it send a smaller payload to the Moon?

Answer (score 6):

Almost certainly. The predecessor [H-IIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-IIA) rocket delivered the orbiter [SELENE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELENE) to the moon in 2007. The [SELENE-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELENE-2) mission slated for 2018 or 2019 will use either an H-IIA or an H-IIB launcher -- it's not entirely clear which from the references I've found, but I think it will be the H-IIA, as the payload is not significantly heavier than that of SELENE.